# Check whether a request is GET or POST 

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP detecting request type (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete)

This should be an easy one.

I have a script, and in the script I want to determine whether the request arrive via `GET` or `POST` method.

What is the correct way to do it?

I am thinking of using something like this

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    // do post
} else  {
    // do get
}
```

But deep in my heart I don't feel this is the right way. Any idea?

Comment: Why can't you try $_REQUEST["variable_name"] if you target processing variables regardless of request type?

Comment: @AnoopPete - because that's not what was being asked. $_REQUEST will accept GET, POST, PUT, DELETE (anything). Not only is this terrible practice, it can lead to security risks. Imagine your logic is simply expecting a form POST method, but you allow any/all methods to be accepted. That could have dire consequences in the wrong hands.

Comment: try using this it will help you wheather form is get or post                               if( $_REQUEST["name"] || $_REQUEST["age"] ) {
      echo "Welcome ". $_REQUEST['name']. "<br />";
      echo "You are ". $_REQUEST['age']. " years old.";
      exit();
   }

Answer (score 925, accepted):

Better use [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}
```

Comment: @Gumbo does we need `===`, what will happen if I used `==`

Comment: You can use `===` *or* `==`. The former is just good practice, as it checks if the variables are 'identical'. (EG: `5 == '5'` is `true`, but `5 === '5'` is `false`)

Comment: Also consider returning 405 if it's neither GET nor POST.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // do post
    } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        // do get
    } else {
        http_response_code(405);
        die();
    }

Comment: According to NetBeans IDE, it's not good to access `$_SERVER` directly. So, in this case, the alternative is `if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') { … }`.

Comment: I've experienced environments where PHP doesn't actively set the $_POST global, so I agree that using the above method works much more reliably.

Comment: @AndrewDownes as u mentioned to use `http_response_code(405);` under which circumstances this will occur. I tried removing method, but it takes default as GET

Comment: @ajinzrathod You can use also `PUT` or `DELETE` method

Answer (score 81):

Use [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php).