# Checking if request is post back in PHP

Tags: php

How can I check if the request is a post back in PHP, is the below ok?

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

where `submit` is the `name` of the `<input type="submit" />`

Comment: Do you want to check if there is `post` data present, or if the `submit` data is present?

Comment: Checking for a post or post back? A post back is a particular type of post request.

Comment: @Steve, @Lèse majesté, basically, I just want to see if a form is post back so I process the post back

Comment: I feel the moderators got a little gung-ho about marking this as a duplicate. This answer is more useful than the alleged "original" in terms of showing someone how to actually and simply detect a POSTBACK to the same page using PHP, which is what the OP's question seems to be asking for.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That will work if you know and expect such a submit button on the same page.

If you don't immediately know anything about the request variables, another way is to check the request method:

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST')
```

As pointed out in the comments, to specifically check for a [postback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback#In_web_development) and not just any POST request, you need to ensure that the referrer is the same page as the processing page. Something like this:

```
if (basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])
```

Comment: You should definitely use `===` instead of `==`. Explanation, why, may be found in comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1372163/1469208) and in many, many other resources, as these are fundamentals of PHP programming.

Answer (score 3):

You want `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`.

Yours is a very similar although less general question than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete).

This is probably a better approach than actually checking a post variable. For one, you don't know whether that variable will be sent along. I have the hunch that some browsers just won't send the key at all if no value is specified. Also, I'd worry that some flavors of PHP might not define `$_POST` if there are no POSTed values.

Comment: You should definitely use `===` instead of `==`. Explanation, why, may be found in comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1372163/1469208) and in many, many other resources, as these are fundamentals of PHP programming.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a generic routine without dependency "method" (post/get) and any other names of the forum elements, then I recommend this

```
<?php
$isPostBack = false;

$referer = "";
$thisPage = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}

if ($referer == $thisPage){
    $isPostBack = true;
} 
?>
```

now the if $isPostBack will be true if it is a postback, false if not.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should do it.

Careful when you're using `image` type submits, they won't send the `name` attribute in some browsers and you won't be able to detect the POST. Smashed my head against the desk a few times until I realized it myself.

The workaround for that is to add a `hidden` type input as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could also use `if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))`