# auto submit form refresh every second

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a little problem with this code :

```
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('bilan.resultat.add', ['bilanId' => $bilan->id] )}}" id="form" name="formu">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sexe</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Taille</th>
            <th>Poids</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-primary">
          <tr>
            <td><input id="age" size="7" maxlenght="3" name="valage" value="{{ $bilan->age }}" readonly></td>
            <td><input size="7" maxlenght="3" name="valtaille" value="{{ $bilan->Taille_cm }}" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" size="2" maxlenght="3" id="anc_id" name="anc_id" value="{{ $bilan->resultat->anc_id }}" readonly></td>
            <td><a href="/bilans" class="btn btn-outline-primary pull-right" role="button">Retour</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="table table-responsive">
        <tr>
          <td><p class="text-primary">Indice de masse corporelle (IMC)</p></td>
          <td><input name="imc" size="5" value="@if($bilan->resultat !== null) {{ $bilan->resultat->imc }} @endif"/></td>
          <td><p hidden class="text-primary">Fréquence cardiaque maximale</p></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="fcm" size="5" value="@if($bilan->resultat !== null) {{ $bilan->resultat->fcm }} @endif"/><a hidden>  b/min</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="text-primary">Distance minimale normale</p></td>
          <td><input name="dmn" size="5" value="@if($bilan->resultat !== null) {{ $bilan->resultat->dmn }} @endif"/><a> m</a></td>
          <td><p hidden class="text-primary">Fréquence cardiaque de travail 50%</p></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="fct50" size="5" value="@if($bilan->resultat !== null) {{ $bilan->resultat->fct50 }} @endif"/><a hidden> b/min</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <a href="/bilans" class="btn btn-outline-primary pull-right" role="button">Retour</a>
    </form>
```

I want to auto load the form when the page is loaded so i add the script :

```
<script>
window.onload = function() { ancrecupid(); calculerIMC(); calculerDMN(); document.getElementById('form').submit(); };
</script>
```

It works but the page is reloaded every second, and i just want the form to be loaded once...
I have several functions to load that's why i put `function() { ancrecupid(); calculerIMC();....`

What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: at the end, you automatically submit, causing page refresh ..

Comment: If the page is reloaded there is no way you can stop window.onload code to execute, except that you get some state from server and make decision based on it. Otherwise dont reload the page each second, only the specific data using ajax.

Comment: You need Ajax for that.  Interested?  This means that javascript will submit the form, without the client noticing anything.

Comment: thank you for response, yes i'm interest using ajax but i don't know how ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your code. It is working as written. What you need is a `flag` that denotes whether your page is loaded via `get` request or via `post` request. Currently, your `JS` code is not able to distinguish between them, that is why it is doing infinite redirection. To fix this you have to return a `flag` from your backend code and use that `flag` in your JS code. You can take help from following link

[Checking if request is post back in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242035/checking-if-request-is-post-back-in-php)

**OR**

You can use `ajax` for this.

Link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, something like this is the idea.  Not sure if you need those other functions anymore

```
$(document)ready(function() {
  var myform = $('#form'); 
  // every 1 second:
  setInterval(function() {
    // send Ajax request, with form data
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: myform.attr('action'),
      data: myform.serialize(),   // this reads all the inputs/select, ... puts it all in the correct format...
      success: function(response) {
        // response holds whatever you echoed with php.  For example you can show that response in a div <div id="response"></div>
        $('#response').html(response);
      }
    });

  }, 1000);
})
```