# isset PHP5 is facultative or not

Tags: php

Why we use `isset` here with `!empty`?
Is it necessarily to use it because isset check whether the variable is set or not and `$_POST` is a superglobal variable already set.

```
 <?php
    include 'Config.php';
    $email  = "";
    $mdp    = "";
    $e = array();
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
     if(!empty($_POST))
     {
      $email  = $_POST['adresse_email'];
      $mdp    = $_POST['motpasse'];
   ...
```

Comment: both ifs are uselless instead you can use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {` to know that it is post rquest. See this qiestion with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372147/check-whether-a-request-is-get-or-post

Answer (score 2):

`isset()` checks if the variable exists, but not it's content.

You use `empty()` later to check if it's an empty string.

In this case, since `$_POST` is an array, and you're not saying which position to pick the value from, `empty()` will check if the array contains any positions.

---

As mentioned in the comments by [Armen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397059/armen), those two verifications are pointless. You could simply check if the request method of the script is `POST`

> ```
> if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
> ```

Comment: isset() checks if the variable exists and we know that $_POST exist so why we use isset? that's my question

Comment: You don't. It's useless.

Comment: Unless you're in a page that didn't come from a form submission.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `isset()` is used to check if the `$_POST` superglobal variable is set, but it's redundant code. `empty()` already includes the functionality of `isset()` but also does more. From the documentation:

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value.
>   Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

... so it will also check if the $_POST array has elements in it (is not an empty array).

For a simple web form checking, using `!empty($_POST)` is easier than writing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`, but the result is the same, if the request was not made through POST, none of them will match.

Additionaly, in your code, you could use `isset()` on the $_POST elements also to rule out the warnings issued by PHP if an index is not defined (if an element wasn't submitted in the form):

```
$email  = isset($_POST['adresse_email']) ? $_POST['adresse_email'] : '';
$mdp    = isset($_POST['motpasse']) ? $_POST['motpasse'] : '';
```