# Why php form not submitting?

Tags: php, html

I'm developing a script for online admission in a website. Below is `php` code of the page. The problem is that it's not submitting.

```
    <?php
include ("include/header.php"), include ("include/config.php");

 if(isset($_POST['applyAdmission'])) {

  $admission_no = $_POST['admission_no'];
  $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];
  $l_name = $_POST['l_name'];
  $p_add = $_POST['p_add'];
  $c_add = $_POST['c_add'];
  $dob = $_POST['dob'];
  $education = $_POST['education'];
  $mobile = $_POST['mobile_no'];
  $course = $_POST['course'];
  $subjects = $_POST['subjects'];
  $timing = $_POST['timing'];

  $filepath_pic = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
  $res_move_pic = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], "/admission/".$filepath_pic);

  $filepath_sign = $_FILES['sign']['name'];
  $res_move_sign = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sign']['tmp_name'], "/admission/".$filepath_sign);

  $agree_terms = $_POST['agree_terms'];
  $agree_cond = $_POST['agree_cond'];


  if ($res_move_pic == 1 && $res_move_sign == 1 ) {

    $query = "INSERT into online_admission (f_name, l_name, p_add, c_add, dob, degree, mobile_no, course, subjects, timing, pic, sign, agree_terms, agree_cond, applied_on) 
             values ('$f_name','$l_name','$p_add','$c_add','$dob','$education','$mobile','$course','$subjects','$timing','$filepath_pic','$filepath_sign','$agree_terms','$agree_cond','now()')";
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR: Unable to insert into database.");

    if ($res == 1) {
      header('Location:http://adarshclasses.in/admission_success.php/');
      exit();
     } else {
      header('Location:http://adarshclasses.in/admission_failed.php/');
      exit();
        }
     } else {
       echo "Error in updateing profile pic and sign";
   }
 } else {
   //echo "Please submit the form, thanks!";
}

;?>
```

Everything in form is correct like I added same name in form which i used in `$_POST` but still it's not working, please help me to fix this issue.

Here is `html` codes of form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="admission_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <!--div class="row">     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="admission_no"> Admission No. </label>
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="admission_no" value="<?php echo $admission_no ;?>" readonly disabled>

  </div>
 </div--><br>


 <div class="row">     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="f_name"> First Name <span class="required">*</span> </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name" placeholder="Your first name" value="<?php echo $f_name ;?>" required>

  </div>     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="l_name"> Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="l_name" placeholder="Your last name" value="<?php echo $l_name ;?>" required>

  </div>
 </div><br>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <label for="p_add"> Permanent Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="p_add" placeholder="Please write your permanent address" value="<?php echo $p_add ;?>" required></textarea>
  </div>
 </div><br>


 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <label for="c_add"> Current Address in Jodhpur <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="c_add" placeholder="Please write your address where you currently living" value="<?php echo $c_add ;?>" required></textarea>
  </div>
 </div><br>  


 <div class="row">     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="dob"> Date of birth <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="Your date of birth eg:- 25/11/1996" value="<?php echo $dob ;?>" required>

  </div>     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="education"> Recent passed degree/exam - </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="education" placeholder="for example - BA/ B.Sc etc." value="<?php echo $education ;?>" >

  </div>
 </div><br>

 <div class="row">     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="mobile_no"> Mobile Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile_no" placeholder="Enter your mobile number, eg - 8384991980" value="<?php echo $mobile_no ;?>" required>

  </div>     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="course"> Select course <span class="required">*</span> </label>

      <select class="form-control" name="course" required>
       <option value="none"> --- Select one course --- </option>
       <option value="IAS"> IAS </option>
       <option value="RAS"> RAS </option>
       <option value="Police constable"> Police constable </option>
       <option value="SI"> SI </option>
       <option value="Railway"> Railway </option>
       <option value="REET"> REET </option>
       <option value="Teacher"> Teacher </option>
       <option value="Patwar"> Patwar </option>
       <option value="Bank PO"> Bank PO </option>
       <option value="Jr Accountant"> Jr Accountant </option>
       <option value="Rajasthan police"> Rajasthan police </option>
       <option value="SSC (10+2)"> SSC (10+2) </option>
      </select>

  </div>
 </div><br>

 <div class="row">     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="subjects"> Subjects - </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subjects" placeholder="Enter your subject you want to read" value="<?php echo $subjects ;?>" required>

  </div>     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="timing"> Classes Timing - </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="timing" placeholder="Your preferred time for coaching" value="<?php echo $timing ;?>" required>


  </div>
 </div><br>

 <div class="row">     
  <div class="col-lg-6">

      <label for="picture"> Upload your picture <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="picture" required>

  </div>     
  <div class="col-lg-6">
      <label for="sign"> Upload your signature <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="sign" required>
  </div>
 </div><br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." name="agree_terms" value="1"> I agree with Rules and Regulations mentioned below.<br>
     <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." name="agree_cond" value="1"> I hearbly declare that Adarsh Classes can use my pictures after my selection for advertising purpose.
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="text" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="applyAdmission"> Submit my application form </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  



   </form>
```

Comment: Kindly post HTML as well. So we can figure out what it is the issue.

Comment: Add the form for completeness

Comment: You mean nothing happens on clicking the submit button? Or the input isn't been saved?? Please be clear in your explanation. And show your HTML as well.

Comment: Have you included your database file?

Comment: Hi @SyedNoman now i added html too.,

Comment: @ZainFarooq yes i added database file too in config.php

Comment: <button type="text" name="submit"  > // what it means ??

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya i edited that and now form is working but giving error that failed to update the pic and sign, as now problem is may be in uploading pic and sign.

Comment: There does remain the issue of using `mysql` functions - take the plunge and start using `mysqli` as that sql is vulnerable

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="applyAdmission"> Submit my application form </button> // try these

Comment: You may wish to change the way you detect a form POST submission: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1372163/3392762

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that in the input type of the HTML Page for the submit you are using `<input type="button"`
instead of `<input type="submit"`. Use `<input type="submit"` that's work.
Example:

```
<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<button>` to `<input>`. Buttons can work with javascript but with only php button cant work with post data. You can not get `POST` data by `<button>`. For this you have to use `<input>`

Change this

```
<button type="text" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="applyAdmission"> Submit my application form </button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="applyAdmission">
```

**Second:**
Here is looking syntax error `include ("include/header.php"), include ("include/config.php");`

PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. Make them seperate by `;` not by `,`.

```
include ("include/header.php");
include ("include/config.php");
```

You can see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) for more deep information

Comment: Hi i edited that way `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="applyAdmission"> Submit my application form </button>` and now it looks working but their is some more problem in uploading sign and picture, can you figure out that too.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: It saying "Unable to insert data" means something is wrong with SQL query comment.

Comment: Its not error man. Use this `mysql_error($connectionvariable);`

Comment: What you mean by `mysql_error($connectionvariable);` I'm a front-end developer and don't know that much, please tell me briefly about this.

Comment: It will tell you about where actually you are wrong in your sql query

Comment: Here I supposed your database connection variable is `$connectionvariable`. You can also change this

Comment: Try this inside die()

Comment: Nothing happened after adding your suggestions.

Comment: I am not in front of your computer. May be problem in your database data type or length.

Comment: try this `include ("include/header.php");` type this in next line `include ("include/config.php");`

Comment: @Jaky. I have added some comment in your post. Please try this

Comment: `Comment all the code below and echo all above values`

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
<button type="text">
```

to

```
<button type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 button type="text" to type="button" Or input type ="submit/button"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this code:

```
<button type="text" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="applyAdmission"> Submit my application form </button>
```

with below code   :

```
<input type="submit" name="applyAdmission" value="Submit my application form" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" />
```

You also need to make sure that your wrote PHP code in same file, otherwise you have to add PHP file name in action tag in below line:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="admission_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You also have some PHP error in your code, so you have to add first line in your PHP code and then fix your PHP Fatal error.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a little syntax error and I think fixing this will fix your issue.

Change

```
include ("include/header.php"), include ("include/config.php");
```

to

```
include ("include/header.php");
include ("include/config.php");
```

To show you the syntax error, here is an example:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

include("test.php"), include("someother.php");
```

The response:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in ...\tests\includeTest.php on line 6
```

#### Incorrect input type

You should also change your button type.

Change

```
<button type="text"...
```

to

```
<button type="submit"...
```

Comment: Considering there is a syntax error in the OPs first line of code, I think that clearly demonstrates they have not yet practised any Php debugging.  So are in effect typing blindly.

Comment: In old versions of php probably you can do everything. It was not much sensitive as new versions. I am not sure though