# Can't return array from php function to ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a javascript file in which I am doing an ajax request to `foo.php`
in order to get an array of mysql results.
Here is my javascript file.

```
//foo.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"foo.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            action:"test",
            remail:"foo"
        },
        success:function(data){
            var messages = data;
            console.log("Ext req");
            try{
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            }catch(e){
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        failure:function(){

        }
    })
});
```

In order to receive my array of results from php I do the following:

```
//foo.php
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        if(empty($action)){
            return;
        }
        switch($action){
            case "test":
                $query = "select * from message where seen";
                $ar = [];
                $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    $ar[] = $row;

                }
               echo json_encode($ar);
            break;
        }
    }            
?>
```

This returns an array of objects to my ajax request which then I can handle according to my needs.
However if I try to move the php code inside the switch statement into a function and return the encoded result of the function I only get an empty array as response.
Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
<?php 
    function test(){
        $query = "select * from message where seen";
        $ar = [];
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $ar[] = $row;
        }
        return $ar;
    }
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        if(empty($action)){
            return;
        }
        switch($action){
            case "test":
                $result = test();
               echo json_encode($result);
            break;
        }
    }            
?>
```

Any ideas why this happening?

## UPDATE

`$con` is a variable that comes from another file which I `include`

Comment: Where do you call the test function?

Comment: Also the function does not have return statement... at least for the JSON encode

Comment: The function does have a return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you moved your query logic into a function, `$con`, MySQL's  connection object is not available. Use `GLOBAL $con;` inside your function.

Read this to understand [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

**Method 1**
Using `GLOBAL` keyword

```
function test(){
    GLOBAL $con;

    $query = "select * from message where seen";
    $ar = [];
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $ar[] = $row;
    }
    return $ar;
}
```

**Method 2**
Pass an argument to a function

```
function test($con){
    $query = "select * from message where seen";
    $ar = [];
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $ar[] = $row;
    }
    return $ar;
}

Call it like this:

test($con);
```

Comment: $con comes from another php file I will update my post

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can fix it with solution i provided. Your query is failing due to no connection found.

Comment: I can accept this answer in 5 minutes.However I cannot understand why isn't  $con available inside my function

Comment: Function has its own scope for variables http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

Global variables if not used carefully can make problems harder to find as other solution suggested. Pass `$con` as argument to your function:

```
function test($con){
        $query = "select * from message where seen";
        $ar = [];
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $ar[] = $row;
        }
        return $ar;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us talk about the problems you have:

1. You pass a `failure` function to `$.ajax`. You surely wanted to use `error` instead of `failure`. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
2. You have a `messages` variable initialized, but unused inside `success`. Get rid of it.
3. You check for `isset($_POST)`, but that will always be `true`. You wanted to check `isset($_POST["action"])` instead, or you wanted to check [whether it is a POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372147/check-whether-a-request-is-get-or-post).
4. `$con` is not available inside the `function`. You will need to either initialize it inside the `function` or pass it to it and use it as a parameter.