# Angularjs not storing variable to $scope after AJAX call within $http.get request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, flickr

I'm using `angularjs` and I can't get the following controller to save to a $scope variable the data returned from an `AJAX` request to Flickr.  The `$http.get` makes a call to a locally saved json file.  Upon success, it uses the json returned in `success()` to determine the appropriate url for the AJAX call to the Flickr API.  Upon success of that call, I log the data to the console.  So far so good, it returns an array of three objects.  However, I'm trying to set that array to a $scope variable (`$scope.photos`) so I can iterate over it my view template.  However, when I try outputing `{{photos}}` in the html there is nothing.  I suspect this is a promise issue, and the template is rendering before the AJAX returns the data from Flickr, but I've been pouring over the docs with no success (looked at `$q` a little).  I'm somewhat new to Angular and would appreciate your insight.  Thanks!

```
artistControllers.controller('PhotoController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $q){
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.artists = data;
    $.ajax({
         type : "GET",
         dataType : "jsonp",
         url : $scope.artists[$routeParams.itemId].flickr,
         success: function(flickr){
            $scope.photos = flickr.items;
            console.log($scope.photos);
         }
    }); 
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Why use jQuery instead of `$http`?

Comment: A valid question @Phil, see below for similar comments.  Short answer is I haven't been able (yet) to successfully call Flickr without $.ajax.

Comment: Here is an answer that might help your flickr issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720547/cant-use-angular-to-show-json-from-flickr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help and feedback.  I have found a solution using $q and $http.jsonp, in part thanks to this tutorial:

http://youtu.be/gApduktFwxw?t=17m

Here is my code, note that my API url string to flickr has `&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK` appended to it:

```
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.artist = data[$routeParams.itemId];
    var url =  $scope.artist.flickr;
    console.log(url);

    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.getImages()
        .then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }, function(status){
            console.log(status);
        });
    };

    $scope.getImages = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function(res){
                defer.resolve(res);
                console.log(res);
            }).error(function(status, err){
                defer.reject(status);
                console.log(err);
            });

        return defer.promise;           
    };

    $scope.init();
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `jQuery.ajax`. Angular's `$http` can do `JSONP` too. You can read more about [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).

```
artistControllers.controller('PhotoController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $q){
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.artists = data;
    $http.jsonp($scope.artists[$routeParams.itemId].flickr).success(function(data){
        $scope.photos = flickr.items;
        console.log($scope.photos);
    });
  });
}]);
```

Comment: I am looking into $http.jsonp, but I have not yet been able to make it work whereas $.AJAX does.  Will continue to strive for pure Angular implementation.

Comment: Here's a random jsfiddle that demonstrates how to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/a4Rc2/114/

Answer (score 7):

Because you are executing code outside of Angular's knowledge, you need to manually call `$scope.$digest()` for it to "see" your change and update the markup accordingly.

Just change your success handler to:

```
 success: function(flickr){
    $scope.photos = flickr.items;
    $scope.$digest();
 }
```

Note: `$scope.$apply()` would also work, because it does a `$digest` of every single scope in your application, starting from the `$rootScope` down. On a big application, this can be much slower than necessary, so in your case I recommend only digesting from the scope you are modifying down.

Comment: This is not ideal. You shouldn't have to manually call `$digest`. `$http` does this for you.

Comment: Correct. I should have mentioned that it would be better to use the Angular `$http` service instead. But if you have to use the jQuery `.ajax()` method, then you do need to do `$scope.$digest()` yourself.

Comment: The way which I was looking for. It just solved the issue thanks.