# JSONP in AngularJS resourse - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, ngresource

I'm trying to rewrite my code using factory:

My current code:

```
$http({ method: "JSONP", url: url}).success(function(data){
 $scope.albums = data.entries;
});
```

is ok

But my new code:

```
app.factory('Album', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource(url, {}, {query: {method: 'JSONP', params: {}}});
}]);
...
$scope.albums = Album.get();
...
```

returns

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/ru-proton/albums/?format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

What I do wrong?

Comment: This should help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js

Comment: No, it can't help: I have no problem with jsonp and $http. I have problem with jsonp and $resource.