# How can I use the Angular $http service to retrieve simple data from the MongoDB REST API?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, rest, callback, jsonp

I have a simple MongoDB that stores temporary dummy data that is accessible company-wide.

I can successfully query the data via the following:

```
$http.jsonp("http://my_server/my_database/my_collection/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&jsonp=angular.callbacks._0")
            .then(getServersComplete)
            .catch(getServersFailed);

        function getServersComplete(response) {
           var test = response.data;
           //do stuff
        }

        function getServersFailed(error) {
           $log.error('XHR Failed for getServers.\n' + angular.toJson(error.data, true));
        }
```

My problem is that Mongo's REST interface is expecting the query parameter `jsonp=my_callback` while Angular's `$http` service is expecting the query parameter `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`.  Angular then translates `JSON_CALLBACK` into its own function, in this case `angular.callbacks._0` (but if there were more callbacks on the page, it would be `angular.callbacks._1`, `angular.callbacks._2`, etc.).  How can I tell Mongo which callback Angular has dynamically created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the `jsonpInterceptor` as described here:
[How to Custom Set AngularJS JSONP Callback Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400891/how-to-custom-set-angularjs-jsonp-callback-name)

```
.factory('jsonpInterceptor', function($timeout, $window, $q) {
 return {
'request': function(config) {
  if (config.method === 'JSONP') {
    var callbackId = angular.callbacks.counter.toString(36);
    config.callbackName = 'angular_callbacks_' + callbackId;
    config.url = config.url.replace('JSON_CALLBACK', config.callbackName);

    $timeout(function() {
      $window[config.callbackName] = angular.callbacks['_' + callbackId];
    }, 0, false);
  }

  return config;
},

'response': function(response) {
  var config = response.config;
  if (config.method === 'JSONP') {
    delete $window[config.callbackName]; // cleanup
  }

  return response;
},

'responseError': function(rejection) {
  var config = rejection.config;
  if (config.method === 'JSONP') {
    delete $window[config.callbackName]; // cleanup
  }

  return $q.reject(rejection);
}
  };
})
```

[His Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5K46izpIxHat3gLqvu7?p=preview)