# Angular2 Yelp API CORS error

Tags: angular, cors, yelp

While implementing the V3 API I face the following CORS problem with my Ionic2/Angular2 application:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

While using the V2 of the API, I was "bypassing" the CORS problem using http.jsonp whish isn't applicable anymore, because the authorization bearer should be added in the header of the GET request (as far as I understood, a Jsonp header can't be modified).

That's why I tried

```
private queryYelp(yelpOAuth:YelpCommunication.YelpOAuthSignature, nextTo:AddressLocation.Location):Promise<{}> {

    let params:URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    params.set('limit', '' + Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.LIMIT);
    params.set('latitude', '' + nextTo.coordinates[0]);
    params.set('longitude', '' + nextTo.coordinates[1]);
    params.set('radius', '' + Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.RADIUS);
    params.set('sort_by', Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.SORT.BEST_MATCHED);

    let headers:Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + yelpOAuth.access_token);
    let options:RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
        search: params,
        withCredentials: true
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.URL, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((businesses:Yelp.YelpBusiness[]) => {
                resolve(businesses);
            }, (errorResponse:Response) => {
                reject(errorResponse);
            });
    });
}
```

or

```
private queryYelp(yelpOAuth:YelpCommunication.YelpOAuthSignature, nextTo:AddressLocation.Location):Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('limit', '' + Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.LIMIT);
        formData.append('latitude', '' + nextTo.coordinates[0]);
        formData.append('longitude', '' + nextTo.coordinates[1]);
        formData.append('radius', '' + Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.RADIUS);
        formData.append('sort_by', Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.SORT.BEST_MATCHED);

        xhr.onload = () => {
            console.log("status " + xhr.status);
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 201) {
                let businesses:Yelp.YelpBusiness[] = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                resolve(businesses);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        };

        xhr.onerror = () => {
            alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
        };

        xhr.open("GET", Resources.Constants.Default.YELP.URL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + yelpOAuth.access_token);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

and both solution weren't successful aka both solution leaded to the CORS error listed above.

Did I miss something or how could I query the Yelp API v3 from Ionic2 / Angular2?

Thx
Best regards

P.S.: Note that my OAuth access_token isn't exposed. The authentication is generated by my backend.

**UPDATE**

After @Thierry Templier answer I found a solution which works for Ionic2.

When debugging in the browser, I query the Yelp API V3 using a proxy. Therefor I add in ionic.config.json file

```
 "proxies": [{
    "path": "/yelp/v3/businesses",
    "proxyUrl": "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses"
 }]
```

and do the query like following

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8100/yelp/v3/businesses/' + 'search', ...
```

note that following would also work

```
this.http.get('/yelp/v3/businesses' + 'search', ...
```

When running in iOS and Android, the proxy should not be use aka not gonna work. Therefor I do the query like following in my service

```
this.http.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search, ...
```

Of course, to have something handy, I write a gulp task which allow me to switch between environments.

But, this solution is only applicable for Ionic2. If I would have to implement it in Angular2 in a website, I would need I guess a proxy too, not sure about it. Therefor I opened a copy of that task in the issues list of the Yelp API V3

https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api-v3/issues/21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't on the client side since the browser will transparently Hamble cross domain requests. It will send under the hood the `Origin` header. The server must handle CORS following this:

- Send the CORS  headers back in the response to enable (or not) such kind of requests.
- Handle preflighted requests if necessary.

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

I had a look at the docs of the v3 version and can see nothing regarding CORS or JSONP. The only remaining solution is to implement a proxy in your server application as a workaround.  I'm aware that it's not ideal but it's the only possible solution I see

Comment: Thx for your answer Thierry, good to know the problem wasn't between my keyboard and my screen. I updated my post with kind of solution using the ionic proxy. I mark then your answer as solved. Merci.