# AngularJS $http.jsonp Geoserver with custom callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, callback

I'm trying to make a $http.jsonp request in angularjs to a geoserver wfs which expects the callback name to be "parseResponse", however I can see the request being made being controlled by angular and set to their standard such as "angular.callbacks._0"

The vendor parameters for the WFS can be found at 
http://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#wms-vendor-parameters which demonstrates that the callback can be set by setting format_options=callback:myCallback in the URL, and by default is set to "parseResponse", however Angular seems to disregard this and add its own callback parameter regardless, which results in the http call failing as parseResponse is undefined

This has left me in the unusual position of having to set the callback name to "angular.callbacks._0" in the URL to get a response from the request, which is obviously a messy solution if i want to make any other calls to this WFS (which I do/will be doing)

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15394/

```
myApp.controller("searchCont",function($scope, $http,$sce){
$scope.name = 'Superhero';   

jsonSchools = "http://inspire.dundeecity.gov.uk/geoserver/inspire/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=inspire:SCHOOL_CATCHMENTS_PRIMARY&%20srsName=EPSG:27700&bbox=338906.9,732790.9,338907.1,732791.1&&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:angular.callbacks._0";

//jsonSchools = "http://inspire.dundeecity.gov.uk/geoserver/inspire/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=inspire:SCHOOL_CATCHMENTS_PRIMARY&%20srsName=EPSG:27700&bbox=338906.9,732790.9,338907.1,732791.1&&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:parseResponse";



var trustedUrlSchools = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(jsonSchools);
            $http.jsonp(trustedUrlSchools).then(function (response) {
               $scope.schools = response.data.features;
               console.log($scope.schools);
            });

});
```

I've set up a JS Fiddle to demonstrate the problem, with the first URL demonstrating the working interim solution and the second commented out URL showing how the URL should in theory look. Notable if you copy the URL itself without the format_options parameter it will still also default to parseResponse

Lastly I came across a previous stackoverflow issue which looks similar at ([how to custom set angularjs jsonp callback name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400891/how-to-custom-set-angularjs-jsonp-callback-name)) but it didn't seem to help and gave generic method undefined errors.

Any help or direction on this problem would be appreciated, I have thus far tried setting jsonpCallbackParam in the http request but to no avail. Hoping this is an oversight on my part that I can put down to inexeperience.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen the [$jsonpCallBacks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$jsonpCallbacks) service [added to Angular 1.5/1.6+](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14795) that allows you to override the way Angular handles callbacks?