# How to setup cors for angularjs to access external api?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

```
getjson.controller('controller', function($scope, $http){
  var url = "http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getsubcategory"; 

  $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.jsondata = data;
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){});
});
```

*(ed's note: added a closing brace to the outer function body.)*

This code gives me the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.api.8coupons.com/v1/getsubcategory. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: [Check this search....](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=enabling+CORS&oq=enabling+CORS&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out an answer.

```
var url = "http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getcategory?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
```

May be it can help someone.

If you get this kind of error change the type from get/post to jsonp

and then in  url append this parameter

```
 "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"
```

without quotes

Comment: It does work. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/13400409/1629696 for a more detailed solution.