# Angular REST cannot return simple data

Tags: angularjs, rest, steroids

I am trying to get a $http REST GET call working in my Appgyver project working but nothing I do seems to come right, always returns an error.

Please note the angular app will be running on mobile devices eventually and then connect to my remote web service.

I've double checked that my custom API is working and returning data correctly in a number of ways, namely:

- hard coded cUrl request running from sh files in terminal - Returns data and correct 200 code
- Tested the API end points in both POSTMAN and Firefox's SOA client.

Putting in my test end point of http://somesite.com/quote-and-buy-performance/druidapi/taxonomy_term returns data as below:

```
[{"tid":"1","vid":"2","name":"ACME Ltd.","description":"","format":"filtered_html","weight":"0","parent":"0","uri":"http://somesite.com/quote-and-buy-performance/druidapi/taxonomy_term/1"},{"tid":"2","vid":"2","name":"ABC Films LTD","description":"","format":"filtered_html","weight":"0","parent":"0","uri":"http://somesite.com/quote-and-buy-performance/druidapi/taxonomy_term/2"}]
```

Even a simple CSRF Token request gives me errors.

Could someone possibly point out where I am going wrong here, the Appgyver site is badly documented and I have tried the Angular RESTful sample which my code below is based upon from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers

Please note the code below is basically Angular.js using Javascript syntax (as opposed to Coffeescript), logging output follows the code

```
angular
.module('main')
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, supersonic, $http) {
    $scope.navbarTitle = "Settings";

    $scope.stoken = "Response goes here";

    $scope.processLogin = function(){
        var csrfToken;

        steroids.logger.log("START CALL: processLogin");

        // $form_login_email_address = $scope.login_email;
        // $form_login_password = $scope.login_password;

        $local_get = "http://somesite.com/quote-and-buy-performance/services/session/token";
        $hal_get_taxterm_index = "http://somesite.com/quote-and-buy-performance/druidapi/taxonomy_term";

        // $http.defaults.headers.common.contentType('application/json');

        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: $hal_get_taxterm_index,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        $http(req)
          .success(function(data, status, headers) {
            steroids.logger.log("Inside http.get() success");
        }).error(function(data, status, headers){
            steroids.logger.log("Inside http.get() WITH ERROR");
            steroids.logger.log('data: ' + data);
            steroids.logger.log('status: ' + status);
        }).then(function(data, status, headers){
            steroids.logger.log("Inside http.get() then");
        });

        steroids.logger.log("END CALL: processLogin");
    }

});
```

**Logging output from calls to steroids.logger.log**

```
View        Time            Level   Message
main#login  16:01:55.219    info    "Inside http.get() WITH ERROR"
main#login  16:01:55.219    info    "data: null"
main#login  16:01:55.219    info    "status: 0"
main#login  16:01:55.64     info    "END CALL: processLogin"
main#login  16:01:55.64     info    "START CALL: processLogin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Separate out your http call into a service. This is a pretty standard way to modularize your code in angular:

```
angular.module('main').factory("SomeService", function($http) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      $http({
        url: "http://somesite.com/quote-and-buy-performance/druidapi/taxonomy_term",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(data);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error!");
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Then to use this in your controller, just include it in your controller declaration and call get like you would a normal method:

```
angular.module('main').controller('LoginController', function($scope, supersonic, SomeService) {
  $scope.navbarTitle = "Settings";
  $scope.stoken = "Response goes here";
  $scope.processLogin = function(){
    var csrfToken;
    steroids.logger.log("START CALL: processLogin");

    SomeService.get();

    steroids.logger.log("END CALL: processLogin");
  }
})
```

Do this and then comment back with your results and we can work from there.

Comment: Garret, thanks for your input, tried this, exact same result basically.

Even wrote basic a REST client using IP Works REST class and this is giving me results, but does not solve my issue that I have to create an app using Appgyver.

Comment: Is there any more information you can get about the error you receive? Also, do you have access to the code for the service?

Answer (score 1):

If your angular's app is within a certain domain, then HTTP request must be made within the same domain.

In your case, you are trying a cross domain request (a request on another domain). You must then make a cross domain request.

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js).

The author uses `$http.jsonp()` to send cross domain requests. There migth be another way to do it.

Comment: The Angular app is going to be running on mobile devices and will be connecting to my web service to login and do simple GET requests. The server web service ofc will be on a specified domain.

Comment: So my answer is your answer

Comment: Apparently so, just trying to implement this now.

Comment: Gregory, I get the same result using your notation. Result returns a status of 0.
Also tried adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to the header without any change in the result.
Seem to be getting nowhere fast, appreciate your help though.