# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - json calling from angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, cross-domain

How to solve cross-domain-issue 
I do call json like this, but here I am getting cross domain error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://.........json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

**my code**

```
app.factory('appServices', function($http){
    var servicesData = {};
      servicesData.homeSearch = function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url   : 'http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/t/tita.json'
        }).success(function(data, status , header, config){
            console.log('Success')
        })
        .error(function(data, status , header, config){
              console.log('error') 
        });
    }
    return servicesData;
});
```

Full code here http://codepen.io/shibinragh/pen/obxGmQ

Sorry I am a beginner in development, I don't know much about cross-domain issue

Comment: `How to solve cross-domain-issue` - the server needs to either emit CORS headers, or have a `jsonp` alternative ... fortunately for you, that URL responds with jsonp, not json, despite returning `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: This means that the server is not allowing requests come from a different domain. You can try and get around this by using `jsonp` or else the server side code needs to be changed to allow CORS

Comment: Understood can you help me with codepen :)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGNOxo try that code. let me know if it works for you

Comment: improved but not success

Comment: headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

Comment: and also may i know which api service you are using i mean php,.net or java ?

Comment: I dont know  which api , I got it from online and I am doing it learning purpose eg: http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/t/tita.json - help me with codepen