# AngularJS http.jsonp callback not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to retrive jsonp data from inside my controller. I want to grab some jsonp data from the url inside $http.jsonp and pass it through a success function that loops through the data and then pushes it into a variable **dataxx** however I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myJsonMethod is not defined

```
 angular.module('app',  ['onsen'])

    .controller('ChartController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
      this.data = [{
        key: 'Data',
        values: []
      }];
      $http.jsonp("https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json?callback=myJsonMethod").
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //what do I do here?
                dataxx.push({"x":9,"y":11},{"x":9,"y":18});
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.error = true;
            }); 

      $scope.data = [{
            key: 'Data',
            values: dataxx
        }];       

    }])

    .factory('d3', [function() {
      return d3;
    }])

    .factory('nv', [function() {
      return nv;
    }])

    .directive('lineChart', ['d3', 'nv', function(d3, nv) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          data: '=',
          height: '@',
          width: '@'
        },
        template: '<svg ng-attr-height="{{ height }}" ng-attr-width="{{ width }}"></svg>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          var svg = element.find('svg'),
            chart;

          var update = function() {
            d3.select(svg[0])
              .datum(scope.data)
              .call(chart);
          };

          scope.$watch(function() { return angular.toJson(scope.data); }, function() {
            if (chart) {
              update();
            }
          });

          scope.$on('chartloaded', update);

          nv.addGraph(function() {
            chart = nv.models.lineChart()
              .showLegend(false)
              .showYAxis(true)
              .showXAxis(true);

            chart.xAxis
              .axisLabel('x')
              .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));

            chart.yAxis
              .axisLabel('y')
              .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));

            nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
              chart.update()
            });

            scope.$emit('chartloaded');

            return chart;
          });
        }
      }
    }]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js

Comment: did you defined function `myJsonMethod`? if not you can use `JSON_CALLBACK`

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [`documentation`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) about the `url` parameter passed to the `jsonp` method:

> Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request.
>   The name of the callback should be the string JSON_CALLBACK.

So:

```
https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Alternatively if you want to use `myJsonMethod` make sure that you have defined such function which will be called:

```
function myJsonMethod(result) {
    ... 
}
```

In your case you used the standard `.success` callback which internally will define a function called `JSON_CALLBACK`.

Unfortunately from what I can see this remote endpoint completely disregards the `callback` query string parameter. The following urls all return the same result which is wrong of course:

- https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json
- https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json?callback=foo_bar
- https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

So I would recommend you talking with the developers that have implemented this API and ask them not to hardcode if possible the callback name but rather to respect the query string parameter.

If for some reason this API cannot be fixed, then your only chance is to define a function called `myJsonMethod` as I showed earlier.