# receiving JSONP data in Angular - jsonCallback is not defined

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I'm trying to receive data in **AngularJs** via **JSONP** using the `$http.jsonp(url)`. I'm new to **AngularJs** and **Javascript** in general. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I used:

```
angular.module('tutorialApp', []).controller('ContentCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    var url = "/somejsonp.jsonp?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

    $http.jsonp(url)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

I keep getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonCallback is not defined

My jsonp looks like this:

```
jsonCallback([
    {
        "from": "Lissabon (LIS)",
        "to": "Bangkok (BKK)",
    },
    {
        "from": "Hamburg (HAM)",
        "to": "Vienna (VIE)",
    }
]);
```

Comment: little confused, you passed `JSON_CALLBACK` and response wrapped in  `jsonCallback`, Ideally it should have wrapped inside `JSON_CALLBACK` only.. are you sure you are getting a response what you have pasted over here?

Comment: Check the server configuration, looks like it somehow attempts to translate the passed callback param into a 'proper' form - which shouldn't be done. The Angular part seems to be correct here.

Comment: I learned here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js) to use callback=?JSON_CALLBACK. But I keep getting "jsonCallback is not defined" (all?callback=angular.callbacks._0:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonCallback is not defined)

Comment: What's the server, do you control it? If you provide another name (like `SONJ_CALLBACK`), what'll be the resulting response?

Comment: You guys are right. I think it might be connected to the htaccess in someone way.  I will have a look into it. Thank you very much so far.