# AngularJS API call

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

Trying to make an API call.

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller("mCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.jsonp("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID={APIKEY}")
       .success(function(data) {
          $scope.data = data;
          console.log($scope.data);

       });
}]);
```

Keep getting a 404 response. I can access the data when using the address in the browser though.

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js

Comment: Are you just missing `http://` in the request url? Check the browsers debugger tools (net/network tab) to see where that request is going. My bet would be to it's treating it as a relative url to the local server/domain.

Comment: You forgot the `http://`. Also, you probably should remove your API Key from public pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using `$http.get('...')` instead of `$http.jsonp('...')`

And second you forgot to add `'http://...'` to the route

The correct way is

```
$http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=d21b99023992fadfa586d8c3589d0b8d")
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log($scope.data);
  });
```

I've tested it, it should work

Comment: Worked, ty, but why not jsonp?

Comment: While you could technically use it, is more of a hassle and you only need a simple get, the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) tells you how but is not worth it.