# parse the content of website designed in PHP and display it in the android app.

Tags: php, android, parsing

My website had been designed using php, now i want to parse the content of website and make it displayed in the android app, which parser should i have to use?? i heared about Json parser and XML parser, i dont have any idea about that, please give me the suggestions,

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You could start with a tutorial about jason parsing: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried browsing to your website from your android phone? No matter what it's written in (PHP, COBOL, ASP.Net), it just returns a bunch of HTML which is rendered by the browser which in this case just happens to be on an Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly a bad approach to parse a website to retrieve its data.

A better way is it to abstract the data layer so several User Interfaces can access it. There is a question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684075/how-to-build-a-restful-api), which deals with RESTful apis with php.

Answer (score 0):

**Question :**

- Is your Website support Responsive Design ?
- Do you want to use same
  view as in your web site ?

As per My Opinion you should use `PhoneGap  Framwork` it will definatily help you.