# Why it doesnt work ? JSON, AJAX, PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im total beginner at PHP, jQuery and AJAX. I try to make a simple website that sets and displays temperature limit using AJAX. I want to read from JSON file and overwrite it with new data after clicking button.

Here is my index.php :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="xxx">

        <title>Temperature Limit</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <link href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h4><b>Type temperature limit</b></h4>

                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="minTemp">Minimal:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="minTemp"       min="10" max="25" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="maxTemp">Maximal:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="maxTemp"  min="25" max="40">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5">
                            <button id="saveTermBut" type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Current Conditions </h2>

            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label " for="currTemp">Minimal Temp:</label>
                        <output id="currTemp">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label " for="currTemp1">Maximal Temp:</label>
                        <output id="currTemp1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
        </footer>

        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js">

        <script src="SaveTempLimit.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my SaveTempLimit.js  :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'tempLimit.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (tempLimit) {
            $('#currTemp.form-group').append(tempLimit.minTemp);
            $('#currTemp1.form-group').append(tempLimit.maxTemp);
        }
    });

    $('#saveTermBut').on('click', function () {

        var limitTemps = {
            minTemp: $('#minTemp.form-control').val(),
            maxTemp: $('#maxTemp.form-control').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'tempLimit.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: limitTemps,
            success: function () {
                console.log(limitTemps);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here is my json file:

```js
{
    "minTemp": "20",
    "maxTemp":"22"
}
```

I'm just wondering what are my mistakes. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what does the console show and error reporting? there's also no real php here

Comment: You can not alter the JSON file on the server with that code if that is what you are trying to do. If you are trying to update the file, you will need to have some sort of serverside code that reads the post parameters and writes to the file.

Comment: It's simple, put </script> after <script src="jquery.js"> you forget! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work:

```
            $('#currTemp').append(tempLimit.minTemp);
            $('#currTemp1').append(tempLimit.maxTemp);
```

The selector `#` is for ID, and `.` for class.

Don't forget put `</script>` after `<script src="jquery.js">`

Comment: Thank you :) I havent seen those.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to save `limitTemps` to your tempLimit.json. This will not work. You can't write to files directly via ajax.

You will need to create an API endpoint in your php that receives `limitTemps`, and then modifies your tempLimit.json from the php.

Here's some good tips on building a REST API with PHP. [How to build a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684075/how-to-build-a-restful-api)

Comment: Yes, I try to save limit temps to tempLimit.json. I kinda wrote something in php but dont know if it's good.

Comment: If it works, but you're worried about the code quality, do a bit of research and then ask a question over on code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you didn't specify what exactly isn't working.

One reason it is not working because the selector `#currTemp.form-group` is wrong. Please refer to the jQuery's documentation regarding selectors.

`#currTemp.form-group` selects an element with `id="currTemp`, and `class` having `form-group`, which clearly doesn't exist in your HTML.

You can try removing `.form-group` from the selector to get it work.