# RESTfull concept

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I'm still confusing about RESTfull concept. I have a service it's like here

```
include '../includeall.php';
$query = Q_GET_FACT_GIVEN_TABLE;

$i = 0;
$queryall = null;
if (isset($_GET['year'])) {
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    $queryall[$i++] = "f.year=" . $year;
}

if (isset($_GET['period_id'])) {
    $period_id = $_GET['period_id'];
    $queryall[$i++] = "f.period_id=" . $period_id;
}

if (isset($_GET['month_id'])) {
    $month_id = $_GET['month_id'];
    $queryall[$i++] = "f.month_id=" . $month_id;]
}

if (isset($_GET['var_in_cat_id'])) {
    $var_in_cat_id = $_GET['var_in_cat_id'];
    $queryall[$i++] = "f.var_in_cat_id=" . $var_in_cat_id;
}

if (isset($_GET['reg_id'])) {
    $reg_id = $_GET['reg_id'];
    if ($reg_id == "prop")
        $queryall[$i++] = "substring(reg_id,-2)='00' AND reg_id<>'0000'";
    else
        $queryall[$i++] = "f.reg_id=" . $reg_id;
}

if (isset($_GET['id_prop'])) {
    $idprop = $_GET['id_prop'];
    $queryall[$i++] = "substring(reg_id,1,2)='$idprop' AND substring(reg_id,-2)<>'00'";
}

if (isset($_GET['data_source_id'])) {
    $data_source_id = $_GET['data_source_id'];
    $queryall[$i++] = "f.data_source_id=" . $data_source_id;
}

for($i=0;$i<count($queryall);$i++){
    $queryi=$queryall[$i];
    $query.=" AND ".$queryi;
}

$query.=" ORDER BY reg_id,month_id";

$database = new Database();
$queryResult = $database->query($query);
$resultArray = Utils::convertToJSON($queryResult);
?>
```

Is my implementation code above can be called as web service??
It's contains of JSON implementation in output as user request on some url.
If it can be categorized as a web service what kind of service do I have??
Can it be call as a RESTfull web service.. 
Please help me..

Comment: SQL injection for god's sake!

Comment: in PHP, you can append an element to an array using the `[]` operator, without that `$i++` you are putting everywhere. Also, there is the [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop  which always is handy to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could consider it a web service, but its interface there's no REST aspect in there. I'd call it ... a search function.

REST(Representational State Transfer) means that the HTTP method defines the action you're taking. For example, a `DELETE` HTTP request will actually cause a deletion, and a `PUT` will write a resource. As presented above, your application consists of a search function, and therefore does not apply.

In php, you can determine the HTTP method used in the request from [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete/359050#359050).

By the way, you should not initialize `$queryall` as null, but `array()`. You can also dispose of the `$i` and just write `$queryall[] = ...` instead of `$queryall[$i++]`.

Also, you should not construct a database query by concatenating input strings, as this code makes your application vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain). Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: many thanks.. I finally understand know. So if I want to implement my service to RESTfull concept. I have to design my service supporting for DELETE PUT or other http request. Thanks for the suggestion of my code. I'am a java coder actually.If you do not mind, Can you give me a modification way to get a RESTfull concept?

Comment: @user816180 For REST to be applicable, your application must manage some kind of data, and allow users to add, edit, and delete said data. Then, you'd probably have code like `switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){case 'PUT': write(); break; case: 'DELETE': delete(); break; ...}`. By the way, as @Ondřej Mirtes pointed out, your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. What happens when the user enters `'; DROP DATABASE; --` in the `year` field?