# PHP: ReSTful handling of Uploaded files

Tags: php, rest, upload

I'm currently creating a web service that receives files(images) and some other data.

The problem is how can PHP 'handle' it? I've read some articles saying i should use PUT method. How do you read it? http://input? POST? FILES?

Comment: helpful question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete

Comment: @diEcho thanks man. but i already know that. just the handling of the uploaded files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Comment: pst...[stream_copy_to_stream()](http://www.php.net/stream_copy_to_stream()) or even just [copy()](http://www.php.net/copy())

Comment: ok. as a follow up, how to test this using shell grep? is it going to be >> grep --upload-file @/some/file/doc.txt https://myapi.com/file