# HTTP header delete in PHP

Tags: php, rest, http, http-headers

I'm developing an API REST and I want my code to distinguish between a GET HTTP HEADER and a DELETE HTTP HEADER for returning the information asked or for removing this info from the database.

Comment: See here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Keep in mind that besides PUT and DELETE aren't supported in all browsers and on some server implementations. You can use the Rails way, and pass a _method parameter to a POST/GET call.