# How to detect HTTP method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, http-method

How can I detect HTTP method in CodeIgniter controller class?

**Edited:**
Is there any other way than using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` in CodeIgniter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP detecting request type (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete)

Comment: I know that, but is it true to use `$_SERVER` variable in CodeIgniter?

Comment: like you use any other variable

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Thanks to Branden, I've found the answer.
`$this->input->server($index)` is identical to `$_SERVER[$index]`.

To get method you can use: `$this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')`.

*UPDATE:* (thanks to [Ecir Hana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1037407/ecir-hana))

As of CodeIgniter 3, using of [method](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::method) is also possible:

```
echo $this->input->method(TRUE); // Outputs: POST
echo $this->input->method(FALSE); // Outputs: post
echo $this->input->method(); // Outputs: post
```

Answer (score 19):

In CodeIgniter 3, you can use the [method](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::method) uhm...method of Input Class.

From the docs:

```
echo $this->input->method(TRUE); // Outputs: POST
echo $this->input->method(FALSE); // Outputs: post
echo $this->input->method(); // Outputs: post
```

Answer (score 5):

You can detect GET and POST by using the Input library.

`$this->input->post()` or `$this->input->get()`

More information can be found: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: From the docs `$this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter` so this does not really answer the question. As it gets data instead of detecting the HTTP method.

Comment: Doesn't work if the (post for example) request doesn't contain any data.