# What does this function do in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't understand this user defined function:

```
function get_or_post($var, $dfvalue = "") {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $value = $dfvalue;
    if (!empty($var)) {
        if ($CI->input->get($var) != FALSE) {
            $value = $CI->input->get($var);
        } else if ($CI->input->post($var) != FALSE) {
            $value = $CI->input->post($var);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Detects HTTP method, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189969/how-to-detect-http-method-in-codeigniter

Comment: it just looks whether there is a value in the superglobal _GET oder _POST array and returns it or returns a default value which is the 2nd parameter

Answer (score 1):

This function checks wheather the $var data is from post or get method using codeigniter's instance.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the CodeIgniter object to a variable. Then assign NULL value for $value.
Inside `if` condition set the value of $value. If the value is coming through get method then set the value by `$CI->input->get($var)` and the value is coming through post method then set the value by `$CI->input->post($var)` .
At last return $value.