# How to use $_GET or $_POST variable to distinguish each type of request?

Tags: php, http, post, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP detecting request type (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete)

I want to display a warning when people submit a form more than one time, and when he use `GET` to request a page the `count` variable reset to 0;

I'm using this technique:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submissioncount" value="<?php echo $subCount; ?>" />
```

But it seems to me $_GET and $_POST alway exist:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET)){
  $warning = "GET exist";
}else{
  $warning = 'GET not exist';
}
if(isset($_POST)){
  $warning2 = "POST exsit";
}else{
  $warning2 = 'POST not exist ';
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
  echo $warning;
  echo $warning2; 
?>
<form acion='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method='POST' >
<input type='submit' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It turns out it aways return exist? Where I did wrong or any other work round for it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete

Comment: @Musa great resources! $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] do the magic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals **exist** whether passed or not, so checking for them will return true. Check entries within them to ascertain if they exist.

`if(isset($_POST['submissioncount'])` or
`if(isset($_GET[some_GET_variable])`

---

Alternately,

```
$meth = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($meth == 'GET')
//do something
else if($meth == 'POST')
//do something else
```

Comment: for `if(isset($_GET[some_variable_set])` part, how to define the variable_set?, the rest part of your answer is great!

Comment: No no. I meant, if you are passing some `$_GET` parameter in your URL as `urlquery?param1=key1&param2=key2`, you can query for param1 as 
`if(isset($_GET['param1'])`

Comment: Got it! Is there any existing urlquery as variable I can use without append param1=key in the end to achieve this? otherwise $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] work fine

Comment: Yes. That is correct. :)