# $_POST variable empty when send POST

Tags: c#, php, json, restsharp

I'm trying to send a `JSON` to my `rest-api` using `RestSharp`. Essentially I've created a model class for the json:

```
public class LogPostData
{
    public string LogMessage { get; set; }
    public string LogStackTrace { get; set; }
    public string LogUserId { get; set; }
    public string LogUserIp { get; set; }
}
```

so I perform the request in this way:

```
 var logPost = new LogPostData();
     logPost.LogMessage = "log message"
     logPost.LogStackTrace = "some content";

 var post = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logPost);

 var client = new RestClient("url of rest api");

 var request = new RestRequest("methodApi", Method.PUT);
     request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
     request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", post, ParameterType.RequestBody);
     request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

 var response = client.Execute(request);
```

as you can see I've created the object `LogPostData` and then serialized it using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

I called the `methodApi` passing as parameter the json.

Now, inside my rest api, I did the following:

```
file_put_contents('debug.txt', serialize($_POST));
```

the content should be the variable that I sended with `RestSharp` on `post` variable, instead I get: `a:0:{}`

why my `$_POST` variable is empty?

Comment: [PHP “php://input” vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: @FirstOne so is not possible valorize $_POST using restsharp?

Comment: I don't know C#, let alone restsharp, so I'm not capable of answering that. Can't you change the PHP portion of the project?

Comment: @FirstOne if I change with `php//input` I get the content sended by php, but this should appear inside $_POST

Comment: @FirstOne you're right, but I remember when I using js in past and executed ajax.Post, the content will fill the php $_POST variable

Comment: Do you ever actually send the request to the server using `client.Execute(request)`?  I don't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: @BrianRogers forgot to add in the example but yes I execute this, example updated anyway

Comment: It’s because you’re doing a PUT request that $_POST is not populated.  You could parse your own $_PUT array without messing up $_POST [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959141).  Or you could use POST instead of PUT

Comment: @James I tried to change the method with POST but the variable `$_POST` is even empty..

Comment: It looks like you might be sending the request body as json.  $

Comment: @James what do you mean? could you please write an example^?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), `$_POST` works with *`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`* and *`multipart/form-data`* content types.  You are sending JSON (*`application/json`*).  Since `$_POST` is an associative array created from posted form data, and you are not posting a form, it's not surprising that it would be empty.

To get the raw JSON from the request body you need to use `php://input`

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

To deserialize the JSON to an object you can use `json_decode`.

```
$logPostData = json_decode($json);
```

If you want the data to be converted into an associative array like `$_POST`, you can pass `true` as the second parameter:

```
$logPostData = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: ok this seems to work just a question: why if I change the method of request to POST: `Method.POST);` I still get `$_POST` empty?

Comment: Because you are sending `application/json` not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I change in the php script the header and setted as: `header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` I also change the request in c# as `new RestRequest("methodApi", Method.POST);` then I added as parameter this: ` request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", post, ParameterType.RequestBody);` so I checked the content of `$_POST` with this: `file_put_contents('debug.txt', serialize($_POST)); ` and I get this : `a:0:{}` what is wrong now?

Comment: If you change the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you have to actually send that type of content, i.e. url-encoded key-value pairs.  You are sending JSON.  They are different types of content.  See [Differences in application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9870523/10263)

Comment: I got it, as I said I changed to `application/json` and when I do this: `$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $json = json_decode(rawData, true);
 
    file_put_contents('debug.txt', $rawData); ` I get nothing inside the file

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you are sending (JSON):

```
header: encoding-type=application/json
body: {"param1":"I like horses", "param2":"they are cool"}
```

This is what PHP needs in a POST request for the $_POST array to work (form submissions)

```
header: encoding-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
body: param1=I%20like%20horses&param2=they%20are%20cool
```

If you are happy with sending json, you need to receive it properly.
If you want to keep using PUT, then make a handler for it that expects JSON.  (Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959141))

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ('PUT' === $method) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    var_dump($data); //$data contains put fields 
}
```