# How to get PUT content from HTTP request in PHP

Tags: php, http

I am trying to declare HTTP `PUT` variable in php. This is my code:

```
<?php 
    ${"_" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']} = /* What should be here? */;
?>
```

I tried `var_dump($_SERVER)` but it does not contain the data sent using ajax request. I am sure there is no problem with `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Dear downvoter. Did you even understand what is my question?

Comment: _“I tried var_dump($_SERVER) but it does not contain the data sent using ajax request”_ - and why should it …? https://lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php, http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: take deeplook @ http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: @CBroe Atleast the question is better than *I am trying to run this code but it gives me error undefined variable*, right?

Comment: Check out this question on how to identify put requests in PHP and how to get the request content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/detecting-request-type-in-php-get-post-put-or-delete

Comment: Also, you question is not valid PHP code. I recommend learning about the syntax on this great [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp).

Comment: @ErikKalkoken It is completely valid, try `${"_PUT"}="hi"; var_dump($_PUT);`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken There is no problem figuring what is the request type, i am concerned about the data sent with it. I am trying to create `$_PUT` as `$_GET`.

Comment: yes, I see it know. Apparently need more coffee ;-)

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I understand, you were probably judging me on based of reputation. Rep is just a number :) Anyways, have a nice day :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP protocol's PUT and DELETE and their usage in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941207/http-protocols-put-and-delete-and-their-usage-in-php)

Comment: @CBroe For treating badly ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there is no official `$_PUT` variable in PHP, you can create one yourself like this:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ('PUT' === $method) {
    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_PUT);
    var_dump($_PUT); //$_PUT contains put fields 
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959141/4379151

Comment: This is something that I was looking for, thank you for your time