# How to distinguish between post and get type of ajax from server-side PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to avoid the ajax url called while page load so that I can maintain of log of posted data from ajax only.

```
if ($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()){ 
 # do the code
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete

Comment: Try google before posting questions here. You can find atleast 5 answers of your question on SO.

Comment: if ($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()){ 
 # do the code
}once the condition $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] DOESN'T WORKS. and my question was for ajax url not php. please go through the question carefully .

Comment: @chettri Wow! You cannot expect people to help you out with that kind of attitude.

Comment: @littleibex  and how bout this one i was not even treating you like that FYI:
Try google before posting questions here. You can find atleast 5 answers of your question on SO. –  Bhavik Shah 17