# RESTful URL for adding record to a record

Tags: rest

What's the correct "RESTful" URL for an action that adds a child record to a parent record?

For example, if I wanted to provide a URL for adding a "comment" record to an "order" record, how should I format it?

My first thought was something like:

```
PUT http://example.com/order/12345/comment/add
```

I work in Django, which uses a similar pattern, so this seemed most intuitive. However, reading over some RESTful design guides [like this one](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html) suggests that this might be bad practice, as they argue the "PUT" and "add" are redundant and therefore might create confusion.

Comment: There is no such thing as "RESTful URL". REST is about links and not URLs.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

```
POST http://example.com/order/12345/comment
```

Comment: Use the POST method if the comment id is generated on the server.

Answer (score 2):

The put action and the add part of the url are redundant.  But there is no hard rule on any of this.  I see apis having that form, even from major vendors, and sometimes simply remark "The put action  and the uri segment are redundant" Sometimes I say nothing at all and just call the endpoint.  If I were writing an api, I would probably leave off the add part.

Comment: But that's still preferable to `/order/12345/add_comment`, right?

Comment: To my eyes /add_comment looks like some sort of entity (which is not your intention, so I might think it misleading as opposed to merely redundant).

Answer (score 1):

there are few points to make your request RESTful:

1) Use resources names in the URL in plural and not in a singular form (orders instead of order)

2) never use ACTION names in your URL such as (ADD) in "comment/add"

3) since you are adding a "NEW" comment without knowing any IDs of hands you should use POST request.

Finally, the URL I would recommend is:

HttpVerbs = POST
http://api.example.com/orders/12345/comments

That should add a new comment to your order#12345

Comment: If you don't specify actions in the URL, then how do you differentiate between actions? e.g. "add" vs "delete"? Relocating that to a POST parameter seems very unintuitive and potentially dangerous.

Comment: your $_Server['REQUEST_METHOD'] will tell you what method you are using.  you will map that request with an action in the backend.  There are also other ways to achieve this.

Comment: Please give this a good read.  Also read the comments. It is very helpful.
http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: you could also use Route Manager

I also found this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to your question. Rest URLs can be whatever you want them to be. At the end of the day, they are routes that get mapped to a method. I wouldn't worry too much about the "best" URL. I prefer to find a standard that works for me and then move on to bigger, more important things. As long as clients know what the URL is, they will be fine.