# php Search field not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have seen one's very like, and pretty much identical to mine on this site, and others across the web. However, after spending three days on multiple forums and youtube, my script does not seem to be working correctly.

I've built a simple page that allows me to track my vehicle miles, and I want to be able to search the table by Location.  Everything works fine except the search function. The table is displayed on the page, filled with all the rows from the sql table. When I type in the search field and click submit, however, the search result is not displayed. Nothing is happening at all.

To help you out a little bit, I will post my code along with my server, php version, and mysql version.

> phpMyAdmin: 4.0.10.7
>
> Database Server:
>
> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
>
> Server type: MySQL
>
> Server version: 5.5.46-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> Protocol version: 10
>
> Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
>
> Web Server:
>
> cpsrvd 11.52.1.3
>
> Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
>
> PHP extension: mysqli

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
echo "      <script>window.top.location='https://mysitehere.com/milelog/login/login2.php'</script>";
exit;
}
?>

<?php
include_once 'carselect/function.php';
connect()
?>

<?php
//The File for the Database Connection
include('editentry/con.php');

//The SQL Query
$table = "SELECT * FROM milelog ";

If($_POST){

$input = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);

$table .= "WHERE Location = '$input'";
}


$show = mysql_query($table) or die(mysql_error());


?>

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/milestyle.css">

</head>

<body class="body">
<div style="border: 1px solid; background-color: silver;"><div class="menuwrap"><ul class="sonarmenu" style="padding: 0 !important;">
<li><a href="addentry.php">Log</a></li>
<li><a href="addcar.php">Add Car</a></li>
<li><a href="list.php">Edit Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="login/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>

<form name="search" action="search.php" method="post">
<input name="location" value="" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="search" name"search" />
</form>

<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Car</td>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Location</td>
<td>Miles</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr> 
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($show)) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Car']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Location']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Miles']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='editentry/delete2.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>    <tr>";
 }
?>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

After 3 long days of researching and not getting anywhere, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "nothing is happening at all"? Is the page posting back? Does anything on the page change?

Comment: @Shi-ii I am open to anything that will work at this point. With the php ajax, is the posting method pretty similar? I will do some research on the ajax search.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie When I type in the search field and then hit the search button, the form seems to be posting (using method post). The page does its quick refresh thing, but nothing on the table seems to change to reflect my search.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in 7.0.0. Just as a test, if you change `$input = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location'])` to `$input = $_POST['location']`, does that work? I'm not a PHP developer, so my apologies if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Thank you for your post. I tried as you suggested and it fixed my problem. Could you offer that up as a answer so I can mark this question answered and give you a vote?

Comment: `if($_POST)` will always be defined unless you've modified you `php.ini` to exclude it which is highly unlikely.

Comment: Done. I've included your comment too, @self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `mysql_real_escape_string`, which was [deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in 7.0.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). The change below will work, but it's not a true solution:

Change

```
$input = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
```

to

```
$input = $_POST['location'];
```

This still leaves you (even more) vulnerable to SQL injection, so you should really be using prepared statements. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for a full example.

Note that as [@self](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654953/self) indicated, the test `if($_POST)` is not the correct way to check whether a post has occurred. One correct way is this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359047/622391) for details):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```