# Problem with the http delete function in Angular, no error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, angular, typescript

I am trying to remove a record from my database. As of now the correct id is passing through as I can see in the Query String Parameters and I am not getting any errors. However, the row is not being deleted, im starting to think it is just a some syntax error but I am unsure.

remove-like.php

```
<?php

$id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: id not found.');

if($_POST) {

include 'connectPDO.php';

try {
    $query = "DELETE FROM likes WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);

    $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
}
```

This is the service file where I am calling it.
forum.service.ts

```
  removeLike(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/remove-like.php?id=${id}`);
  }
```

Then this is the part where I am calling that function in my component.
topics.component.ts

```
  clickDislike() {
    this.forumService.removeLike(this.dataService.getToken() + 'topic' + this.forumService.getLikeToken()).subscribe(result => {
  this.ngOnInit();
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never enter inside your condition block, because `if ($_POST)` will always return `false` in your case. Indeed, you call this endpoint with an http DELETE request with an empty body.

```
<?php

$id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: id not found.');

include 'connectPDO.php';

try {
    $query = "DELETE FROM likes WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);

    $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
```

If you want to make sure your endpoint is called with the right HTTP verb, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/detecting-request-type-in-php-get-post-put-or-delete), and add:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE') {
     // Your code
}
```

Also, I recommend that you add a security mechanism if it's not already the case (e.g. authentication control), as a publicly available endpoint that deletes rows is a security issue.